# MUI Datagrid V5 change Footer height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been looking everywhere to change the footer height on a DataGrid to no avail. I was hoping for a simple solution like headerHeight but it doesn't seem to exist. I'm crazy or blind in my searching in the docs. Thank you.

Comment: please have you found something useful ?

Comment: I have not found anything